# Moq with testing an array class

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, moq

I need a proper way to test one of my classes,I am quite new to any mocking frameworks [image: my project structure looks like this]

I have the below Test class am using Nunit with Moq. I am getting confused as to how I should pass an array of `carconfigs` while making the call like below.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class RaceCarSetupSelectorTest
    {
        private  CarConfiguration _carConfiguration;
        private  RaceCarSetupSelector _raceTrack;
        private  Mock<IRankCalculator> _mockRankCalcultor;        

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _mockRankCalcultor = new Mock<IRankCalculator>();  
            _raceTrack = new RaceCarSetupSelector(_mockRankCalcultor.Object);
        }

        [Test]       
        public void RankingCarConfigurationsTest()
        {
            IList<CarConfiguration> carConfigs = new List<CarConfiguration>();
            carConfigs.Add(FakeCarConfigs.Bentley);
            carConfigs.Add(FakeCarConfigs.Jaguar);
            carConfigs.Add(FakeCarConfigs.Maruti);
            carConfigs.Add(FakeCarConfigs.Nissan);
            carConfigs.Add(FakeCarConfigs.Porsche);

            _mockRankCalcultor.Verify(x=>x.RankConfigurations(It.IsAny<RaceTrack>,It.IsAny<List<CarConfiguration>>)).

        }
    }
```

Basically I want to test the `RankConfiguration` method which is defined in `IRankCalculator` interface.

I have a two entities RaceTrack and CarConfiguration, and I have to rank the carconfigurations based on some input. I have a RankCalculator class in which the actual method for calculation is there like below which derives from IRankCalculator interface.

```
 public CarConfiguration[] RankConfigurations(RaceTrack raceTrack, CarConfiguration[] configs)
        {
         //code for calculation

          return configs[];

        }
```

I have a different class called RaceCarSetupSelector which acts like a service class which calls the method in  RankCalculator class. So I have written a test for the class 'RaceCarSetupSelector '. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Which method? What is the expected behavior/output?

Comment: You are still mocking the actual class you are trying to test (IRankCalculator). This class should not be mocked, only it's dependencies.

Comment: I did not understand your comment. Could you please explain a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I want to test the RankConfiguration method which is defined in IRankCalculator interface.

This implies that the system under test ([SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)) is the `RankCalculator` class and you want to make sure that it is calculating ranks correctly. In your example code however, you aren't using `RankCalculator`, you are using a mock of `IRankCalculator`. To test `RankCalulator` you would do something like

```
// Arrange
var raceTrack = new FakeRaceTrack();
var carConfigs = new List<CarConfiguration> {FakeCarConfigs.Bentley, FakeCarConfigs.Jaguar, ...};
var rankCalculator = new RankCalculator();    // SUT

// Act
var ranks = rankCalculator.RankConfigurations(raceTrack, carConfigs);

// Assert
Assert.That(ranks.First(), Is.EqualTo(FakeCarConfigs.Jaguar));
```

It looks like you are trying to test the `RaceCarSetupSelector` class to make sure that at some point it calls `RankConfiguration()` on `IRankCalculator` (behavior verification). You are almost there, but your test seems to be missing the actual method call you are trying to test. I would imagine it should look something like

```
// Arrange
var raceTrack = new FakeRaceTrack();
var carConfigs = new List<CarConfiguration> {FakeCarConfigs.Bentley, FakeCarConfigs.Jaguar, ...};
var mockRankCalcultor = new Mock<IRankCalculator>();  
var setupSelector = new RaceCarSetupSelector(mockRankCalcultor.Object);    // SUT

// Act
setupSelector.DoSomething(raceTrack, carConfigs);

// Assert
mockRankCalcultor.Verify(x => x.RankConfigurations(raceTrack, carConfigs);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, That helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you don't want to mock the actual class under test you want to mock it's dependencies. You need to create the concrete instance of the class that implements your IRankCalculator and look to test that.

Then the next question is what is it you want to test on that method?